# In what situation will textinput onEndEditing excute in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

Here is my code of TextInput

```
                    <TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor="white"
                        onEndEditing={() =>
                            handleBarCodeScanned({ data: textSearchData })//function
                        }
                        onKeyPress={(e) => {
                            console.log(e.nativeEvent.key);
                        }}
                        onChangeText={(text) => {
                            settextSearchData(text.toUpperCase());//useState
                        }}
                    />
```

It successfully excute while "enter" pressed. But when I type something and dismiss keyboard by android backward button and press another button on APP to navigate to a new page, this function will also be called. So I tried to use onKeyPress instead of onEndEditing, but when "enter" pressed, there is nothing come out from the console. Other characters, included "backspace", works well.

Comment: `onSubmitEditing` is probably what you're looking for and should only be called when Enter is pressed.